# How do multiple array object loop in JSON using PHP

Tags: php, html, json

My JSON format file is like that

```
[
    {
        "closerate":"97.29",
        "mcap":"112579.55263540648",
        "newdate":"19-Mar-18",
        "out_share":"1157.1544"
    },
    {
        "pelast4q":"20.83297644539615",
        "amount":"4.67"
    }
]
```

I want to display data through loop

```
foreach ($data as  $nt) {
   echo "<tr class='table_row_grey'>
             <td ><strong>Price Date</strong></td>
              <td >  $nt[newdate]</td>";

   echo "<tr class='table_row_white'>
              <td ><strong>Close Price</strong></td>
              <td >PKR</td>
             <td > "  . number_format($nt[closerate],2) . " </td></tr>";
   echo "<tr class='table_row_grey'>
              <td ><strong>Shares</strong></td>
            <td >Mn</td>
            <td >" . number_format($nt[out_share],2) . "</td></tr>";
   echo "<tr class='table_row_white'>
            <td ><strong>M.Cap</strong></td>
            <td >PKR Mn</td>
           <td >" . number_format($nt[mcap],0) . "</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr class='table_row_grey'>
                   <td ><strong>P/E</strong></td>
                    <td >Trailing (4Q)</td>
                  <td > " . number_format($nt[pelast4q],2) . "</td></tr>";

}

// Close the table
echo "</table>";
```

What can I do when I am using loop two times display in table

Comment: what exactly is the problem? (apart from a missing `</tr>`, inconsistent column count)

Comment: how you are creating this json output ?

Comment: a problem has two-time display in a table  when I apply loop

Comment: i creating a file in json format like this  $file_name = 'table1.json';
$mydata= json_encode($datatable1);

if(file_put_contents($path,$mydata)){
 
 echo $file_name . 'file Created';
}

Answer (score 0):

you need to :

```
$data = json_decode([{"closerate":"97.29","mcap":"112579.55263540648","newdate":"19-Mar-18","out_share":"1157.1544"},{"pelast4q":"20.83297644539615","amount":"4.67"}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$data_arr = file_get_contents('test.json');
$data = json_decode($data_arr, true);
$new_date = NULL;
$closerate = NULL;
$mcap = NULL;
$pelast4q = NULL;
foreach ($data as $nt) {
    if (! empty($nt["newdate"])) {
        $new_date = $nt["newdate"];
    }
    if (! empty($nt["closerate"])) {
        $closerate = number_format($nt["closerate"], 2);
    }
    if (! empty($nt["out_share"])) {
        $out_share = number_format($nt["out_share"], 2);
    }
    if (! empty($nt["mcap"])) {
        $mcap = number_format($nt["mcap"], 0);
    }
    if (! empty($nt["pelast4q"])) {
        $pelast4q = number_format($nt["pelast4q"], 2);
    }
}
echo "<tr class='table_row_grey'>
             <td ><strong>Price Date</strong></td>
              <td >. $new_date.</td>";

echo "<tr class='table_row_white'>
              <td ><strong>Close Price</strong></td>
              <td >PKR</td>
             <td > " . $closerate . " </td></tr>";
echo "<tr class='table_row_grey'>
              <td ><strong>Shares</strong></td>
            <td >Mn</td>
            <td >" . $out_share . "</td></tr>";
echo "<tr class='table_row_white'>
            <td ><strong>M.Cap</strong></td>
            <td >PKR Mn</td>
           <td >" . $mcap . "</td></tr>";
echo "<tr class='table_row_grey'>
                   <td ><strong>P/E</strong></td>
                    <td >Trailing (4Q)</td>
                  <td > " . $pelast4q . "</td></tr>";

// Close the table
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: I don't use if conditions I have a lot of data display in table in <td> I want to solve that using the loop

Answer (score 0):

**First** convert json to array

```
$data = json_decode('[ { "closerate":"97.29", "mcap":"112579.55263540648", "newdate":"19-Mar-18", "out_share":"1157.1544" }, { "pelast4q":"20.83297644539615", "amount":"4.67" } ]',true);
```

**Then** loop you data

```
echo "<table >";
foreach ($data as  $nt) {

   echo "<tr class='table_row_grey'> <td ><strong>Price Date</strong></td> <td >  ". isset($nt['newdate']) && !empty($nt['newdate'])  ? $nt['newdate'] : "-" ."</td></tr>";

   echo "<tr class='table_row_white'>
              <td ><strong>Close Price</strong></td>
              <td >PKR</td>
             <td > "  . isset($nt['closerate']) && !empty($nt['closerate']) ? number_format($nt['closerate'],2) : "-" . " </td></tr>";
   echo "<tr class='table_row_grey'>
              <td ><strong>Shares</strong></td>
            <td >Mn</td>
            <td >" . isset($nt['out_share']) && !empty($nt['out_share']) ? number_format($nt['out_share'],2) : "-" . "</td></tr>";
   echo "<tr class='table_row_white'>
            <td ><strong>M.Cap</strong></td>
            <td >PKR Mn</td>
           <td >" . isset($nt['mcap']) && !empty($nt['mcap']) ? number_format($nt['mcap'],0) :"" . "</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr class='table_row_grey'>
                   <td ><strong>P/E</strong></td>
                    <td >Trailing (4Q)</td>
                  <td > " . isset($nt['pelast4q']) && !empty($nt['pelast4q'])  ? number_format($nt['pelast4q'],2) : "" . "</td></tr>";

}

// Close the table
echo "</table>";
```